# Computer stopped detecting monitors

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-catalyst

I have a pc with a AMD E6760 graphics, 6 outputs, 5 are in use.
All monitors have been checked with other hardware confirmed to be working fine.

The pc was running fine until after a reboot, at this time only 1 monitor was being detected.
After the next reboot nothing appeared on any screen. 
Any number of reboots, un plugging replugging didn't change this.

I attempt to login via VNC and I get this 
[image: weird vnc]

I had logged in via VNC the day before - and was fine. 
I can login via RDP and I think because it creates it's own graphics adapter etc this is the reason this works.

I uninstalled the graphics drivers, and after this I get a generic single monitor appearing via vnc, but this doesn't output to any of the graphics outputs so still not detecting monitors. Reinstalling the drivers results in the same as the pic and no output...

This has now happened on two PC's (identical hardware)

They are running Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: Have you tried entirely different monitors?  Windows keeps information about a monitor, I had a problem where my 2 monitors would work before Windows booted, but once in Windows the second monitor wouldn't go online.  I could only solve it by switching the two monitors around, nothing else would work.  In other words physically switch the two computers and see if it will work then.

Comment: We have tried a different set of monitors. Today we've ruled out hardware as the cause by swapping the hard drive from a working one. It's definitely something in the os/ drivers/ software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the version of Catalyst driver if they are 2012 updating to the 2014 or 2015 may have a big impact on the issue.